# Convert MAC addresses (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a formula in Excel, which can convert MAC address format ***11:22:33:44:55:ab*** to ***1122-3344-55ab***?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nest SUBSTITUTES:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","-",4),":","-",2),":","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I put the formula in B1 cell it gives me: "There's a problem with this formula". Is there anything that I make wrong or have to make some settings?

Comment: Do you need to use `;` instead of `,` as your delimiter in your formulas?

Comment: When I paste it in B1 cell and press enter it shows me this window: https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/38b1b648-6844-4b27-80db-638e4b8f225c.png

Comment: Did you try changing all the `,` to `;`.  Depending on one's local setting the delimiter may be different.  I am EN-US which uses `,` but many localities use `;`  that would throw that error.

Comment: It works! I tried it before to post the picture, but may be there was some input error. Now everything is fine! Thank you again!